# Getting value from textbox in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox

```
private void search(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (number.Text < 455)
    {
        string site;
        site = number.Text;
        var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("def/f" + site + ".html", UriKind.Relative));
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream);
        browser.NavigateToString(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Value between 1 to 454");
    }
}
```

I gave 
     InputScope="Number"
in TextBox. So the user cant type words.
gave  I have created the button with name, so if button pressed search function will be called. I need to validate that the user entered text in between 1 to 454. If it is, it should go on. Other wise i should alert them like i do above. But it shows error like,

`Error  1   Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing `Text` which is string with integer which is `455`. Before comparison convert the text to integer and do this.

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(number.Text) < 455)
```

Here is your solution

```
int num = 0;

if (int.TryParse(number.Text, out num) && num > 0 && num < 455)
{
    string site;
    site = number.Text;
    var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("def/f" + site + ".html", UriKind.Relative));
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream);
    browser.NavigateToString(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Enter Value between 1 to 454");
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much. It works perfectly. But 1 more doubt. If i gave nothing (means null value), it breaks the app. what should i do now ?

Comment: This doesn't handle the case where a user enters 'Foo'

Comment: @RQDQ: I have mentioned that to OP.

Comment: @MohamedThaufeeq: Wait. I will add fullproof answer.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal i am waiting bro

Answer (score 1):

Well, the message should tell you what is wrong. `Text` is a `string` and you are using it as an `int`.

```
private void search(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int n;
    if(int.TryParse(number.Text, out n))
    {
       if (n < 455)
       {
           var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("def/f" + number.Text + ".html", UriKind.Relative));
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream);
           browser.NavigateToString(sr.ReadToEnd());
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Enter Value between 1 to 454");
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee that the user will type a valid number, so this is one way to check:

```
int parsed;

if (int.TryParse(number.Text, out parsed) && parsed < 455)
{
    // Logic to execute when valid
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Enter Value between 1 to 454");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use either `Convert.ToInt32()` or `int.TryParse()` to convert your string to an integer in order to do the comparison. You can't directly compare strings and integers the way you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Common C# question

```
int iNumber = -1;
if(int.TryParse(textBoxNumber.Text, out iNumber))
{
 // iNumber now have value you can check
 // ...
}
else { } // failed to parse string
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this probably: we should check  (num > 0 && num < 455). We should check -ve values as well.

```
int num = -1

if(int.TryParse(number.Text, out num))
    {
       if (num > 0 && num < 455)
       {
         //Do here 
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Enter Value between 1 to 454");
       }
    }
```